# Estructuras dinamicas con punteros/arreglos dinamicos: malloc(): invalid size (unsorted)

Tags: c, api, punteros, curl, estructuras

Estoy haciendo un trabajo practico para la facultad en el que tengo que utilizar una o mas APIs para recibir información, procesarla y enviarla a un bot de telegram. Todo se hace con libcurl. Por ahora estoy solo con la parte de recibir datos, pero algo me esta deteniendo y no puedo saber que es exactamente. La api con la que estoy teniendo problemas es con la del Servicio Meteorológico Nacional Argentino. La cadena que devuelve es mas un csv que un json, entonces tuve que implementar mi propio código para poder extraer los elementos de cada localidad. Por ahora solo es capaz de recibir los datos meteorológicos del momento, por lo que los otros menues no funcionan.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <curl/curl.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

typedef struct {
    char *string;
    size_t size;
} string_buffer_t;

typedef struct {
    uint8_t day;
    uint8_t month;
    uint16_t year;
} api_date_t;

typedef struct {
    char *location;
    size_t locStrSize;
    uint8_t day;
    uint8_t month;
    uint16_t year;
    uint8_t hour;
    uint8_t minute;
    char *status;
    size_t stsStrSize;
    uint8_t visibility;
    float temperature;
    float temperatureST;
    uint8_t relativeHumidity;
    char windDirection[4];
    uint8_t windSpeed;
    float atmosphericPressure;
} tiepre_location_t;

char *meses[] = {"Enero", "Febrero", "Marzo", "Abril", "Mayo", "Junio", "Julio", "Agosto", "Septiembre", "Octubre", "Noviembre", "Diciembre"};

void init_buff(string_buffer_t *);
void free_buff(string_buffer_t *);
size_t write_callback(void *, size_t, size_t, void *);
//uint8_t i_menu();
void request_smn(char *, char *, CURL *, string_buffer_t *);
uint16_t get_location_cuantity_tiempre(string_buffer_t *smnApiResponse_s);
void catalog_tiepre_request(string_buffer_t *, tiepre_location_t *);
void extract_location_tiempre(char *, tiepre_location_t *);
void extract_date_tiempre(char *, tiepre_location_t *);
void extract_time_tiempre(char *, tiepre_location_t *);
void extract_status_tiempre(char *, tiepre_location_t *);
void extract_visibility_tiempre(char *, tiepre_location_t *);
void extract_temperature_tiempre(char *, tiepre_location_t *);
void extract_temperatureST_tiempre(char *, tiepre_location_t *);
void extract_relative_humidity_tiempre(char *, tiepre_location_t *);
void extract_wind_tiempre(char *, tiepre_location_t *);
void extract_atmospheric_pressure_tiempre(char *, tiepre_location_t *);

int main() {
    char *dateApiUrl = "https://tools.aimylogic.com/api/now?tz=America/BuenosAires&format=dd/MM/yyyy";    // URL de donde extraer la fecha de hoy
    char *smnApiUrl = "https://ssl.smn.gob.ar/dpd/descarga_opendata.php?file=";    // URL de donde extraer los datos
    char *telegramApiUrl = "";        // URL a donde publicar los datos
    char *megacadena = "Azul;29-Octubre-2023;20:00;Cubierto;15 km;14.8;No se calcula; 55;Este  14;989.8 / \r\nBahía Blanca;29-Octubre-2023;20:00;Cubierto;15 km;16.8;No se calcula; 26;Oeste  35;997.8 / \r\nBenito Juárez;29-Octubre-2023;15:00;Algo nublado;12 km;20.6;No se calcula; 35;Sur  33;980.2 / \r\nBolívar;29-Octubre-2023;20:00;Parcialmente nublado;15 km;18.7;No se calcula; 57;Sur  14;994.1 / \r\nCampo de Mayo;29-Octubre-2023;20:00;Algo nublado;10 km;20.2;No se calcula; 80;Este  11;1001.4 / \r\nCoronel Suarez;29-Octubre-2023;18:00;Algo nublado;15 km;17.4;No se calcula; 32;Sur  18;977.7 / \r\nDolores;29-Octubre-2023;20:00;Cubierto con llovizna en la hora anterior;10 km;13.7;No se calcula; 65;Este  18;1006 / \r\nEl Palomar;29-Octubre-2023;20:00;Algo nublado;10 km;21.5;No se calcula; 75;Sudeste  14;1002.6 / \r\nEzeiza;29-Octubre-2023;20:00;Algo nublado;10 km;20.2;No se calcula; 74;Sudeste  18;1002.1 / \r\nJunín;29-Octubre-2023;20:00;Despejado;12 km;20.2;No se calcula; 81;Sudeste  14;992.9 / \r\nLa Plata;29-Octubre-2023;20:00;Parcialmente nublado;10 km;18.6;No se calcula; 76;Sudeste  18;1003 / \r\nLas Flores;29-Octubre-2023;18:00;Cubierto;15 km;20.4;No se calcula; 72;Este  3;997.8 / \r\nMar del Plata;29-Octubre-2023;20:00;Cubierto;10 km;15.5;No se calcula; 58;Sudeste  5;1005 / \r\nMariano Moreno;29-Octubre-2023;20:00;Algo nublado;10 km;22;No se calcula; 69;Sudeste  14;1000.6 / \r\nMerlo;29-Octubre-2023;20:00;Algo nublado;10 km;21.6;No se calcula; 69;Este  9;1001.7 / \r\nMorón;29-Octubre-2023;20:00;Despejado;10 km;23.2;No se calcula; 71;Este  9;1001 / \r\nNueve de Julio;29-Octubre-2023;18:00;Algo nublado;15 km;23.1;No se calcula; 62;Sudeste  11;993.8 / \r\nOlavarría;29-Octubre-2023;20:00;Parcialmente nublado;15 km;15.2;No se calcula; 50;Este  13;987.4 / \r\nPehuajó;29-Octubre-2023;20:00;Algo nublado;15 km;19.2;No se calcula; 66;Este  14;994 / \r\nPigué;29-Octubre-2023;20:00;Parcialmente nublado;20 km;15;No se calcula; 35;Sur  14;971.4 / \r\nPunta Indio B.A.;29-Octubre-2023;20:00;Cubierto;10 km;18.4;No se calcula; 88;Sur  25;1003.9 / \r\nSan Fernando;29-Octubre-2023;20:00;Algo nublado;10 km;21.3;No se calcula; 77;Sudeste  18;1003.4 / \r\nTandil;29-Octubre-2023;20:00;Parcialmente nublado;15 km;14;No se calcula; 53;Sudeste  13;986.4 / \r\nTrenque Lauquen;29-Octubre-2023;15:00;Despejado;15 km;23.9;No se calcula; 33;Sudeste  18;992.6 / \r\nTres Arroyos;29-Octubre-2023;18:00;Parcialmente nublado;15 km;19.3;No se calcula; 19;Sudoeste  24;991.4 / \r\nVilla Gesell;29-Octubre-2023;20:00;Nublado;10 km;14.7;No se calcula; 56;Sudeste  13;1007 / \r\nAeroparque Buenos Aires;29-Octubre-2023;20:00;Algo nublado;10 km;21.1;No se calcula; 70;Sudeste  25;1003.6 / \r\nBuenos Aires;29-Octubre-2023;20:00;Algo nublado;10 km;21.8;No se calcula; 73;Este  9;1001.3 / \r\nCatamarca;29-Octubre-2023;20:00;Parcialmente nublado con relámpagos sin truenos;20 km;34.4;No se calcula; 19;Este  24;944.6 / \r\nTinogasta;29-Octubre-2023;18:00;Algo nublado;20 km;34;No se calcula; 10;Oeste  33;868.9 / \r\nPcia. Roque Saenz Peña;29-Octubre-2023;20:00;Parcialmente nublado con relámpagos sin truenos;20 km;33.3;37.2; 50;Este  14;988 / \r\nResistencia;29-Octubre-2023;20:00;Algo nublado con relámpagos sin truenos;15 km;28.6;32.9; 75;Este  11;993.3 / \r\nComodoro Rivadavia;29-Octubre-2023;20:00;Nublado con chaparrón de lluvia;10 km;5;1.5; 87;Sudoeste  16;997.7 / \r\nEsquel;29-Octubre-2023;20:00;Nublado con nevada;1.2 km;0.4;-3.1; 79;Sudoeste  11;913.4 / \r\nPaso De Indios;29-Octubre-2023;18:00;Cubierto con precipitación a la vista;28 km;8;3.7; 31;Sudoeste  33;944.6 / \r\nPuerto Madryn;29-Octubre-2023;20:00;Parcialmente nublado;30 km;9.7;7.6; 46;Oeste  14;985.6 / \r\nTrelew;29-Octubre-2023;20:00;Nublado con precipitación a la vista;30 km;11.9;No se calcula; 44;Calma;996.6 / \r\nCórdoba;29-Octubre-2023;20:00;Despejado;15 km;26.8;26.8; 42;Sur  11;944.6 / \r\nCórdoba Observatorio;29-Octubre-2023;20:00;Despejado;10 km;29.7;No se calcula; 24;Sudeste  9;952 / \r\nEsc. Aviación Militar;29-Octubre-2023;20:00;Despejado;10 km;28.6;28.5; 43;Sudeste  11;944.6 / \r\nLaboulaye;29-Octubre-2023;20:00;Despejado;10 km;21.7;No se calcula; 65;Sur  3;986 / \r\nMarcos Juárez;29-Octubre-2023;20:00;Algo nublado;20 km;25.6;No se calcula; 57;Este  18;986.8 / \r\nPilar Obs.;29-Octubre-2023;20:00;Despejado;10 km;28.6;No se calcula; 36;Sudeste  7;961.4 / \r\nRío Cuarto;29-Octubre-2023;20:00;Despejado;15 km;22;No se calcula; 62;Este  11;953 / \r\nVilla Dolores;29-Octubre-2023;20:00;Despejado;30 km;29;No se calcula; 15;Noroeste  7;935.4 / \r\nVilla María Del Río Seco;29-Octubre-2023;20:00;Algo nublado;15 km;29.8;No se calcula; 15;Calma;958.5 / \r\nCorrientes;29-Octubre-2023;20:00;Algo nublado;10 km;28.2;33.2; 83;Este  11;992.8 / \r\nItuzaingó;29-Octubre-2023;20:00;Despejado;15 km;26.6;29.7; 90;Noreste  5;993.1 / \r\nMercedes;29-Octubre-2023;20:00;Parcialmente nublado;15 km;25.2;No se calcula; 80;Este  7;989.8 / \r\nMonte Caseros;29-Octubre-2023;20:00;Parcialmente nublado;20 km;26.8;27.5; 68;Noreste  16;996.5 / \r\nPaso De Los Libres;29-Octubre-2023;20:00;Nublado;10 km;25;No se calcula; 85;Sudeste  5;994.6 / \r\nConcordia;29-Octubre-2023;20:00;Nublado;15 km;26.8;28.6; 71;Calma;998.6 / \r\nGualeguaychú;29-Octubre-2023;20:00;Nublado;15 km;25.6;No se calcula; 76;Este  7;999.8 / \r\nParaná;29-Octubre-2023;20:00;Nublado con relámpagos sin truenos;15 km;28;29.1; 56;Noreste  11;991.3 / \r\nFormosa;29-Octubre-2023;20:00;Despejado;20 km;30;36.8; 76;Este  3;992.5 / \r\nLas Lomitas;29-Octubre-2023;20:00;Algo nublado;20 km;35;37.2; 40;Este  3;982.2 / \r\nMount Pleasant Airport (Islas Malvinas);29-Octubre-2023;20:00;Cubierto;30 km;4.7;0.4; 93;Sur  22;971.6 / \r\nLa Quiaca;29-Octubre-2023;20:00;Algo nublado;30 km;17.5;No se calcula; 5;Noroeste  9;664.4 / \r\nJujuy;29-Octubre-2023;20:00;Algo nublado con relámpagos sin truenos;15 km;32.9;No se calcula; 27;Norte  5;898.6 / \r\nJujuy Universidad Nacional;29-Octubre-2023;15:00;Algo nublado;15 km;35;No se calcula; 26;Sudeste  3;858.6 / \r\nGeneral Pico;29-Octubre-2023;20:00;Despejado;20 km;21.2;No se calcula; 43;Este  20;985.7 / \r\nVictorica;29-Octubre-2023;15:00;Despejado;40 km;23.2;No se calcula; 26;Este  14;966.6 / \r\nSanta Rosa;29-Octubre-2023;19:00;Parcialmente nublado;30 km;20.9;No se calcula; 31;Este  16;981.8 / \r\nChamical;29-Octubre-2023;20:00;Algo nublado;20 km;32.4;No se calcula; 15;Calma;944.8 / \r\nChepes;29-Octubre-2023;15:00;Despejado;20 km;38;No se calcula; 7;Sur  9;924.7 / \r\nChilecito;29-Octubre-2023;15:00;Algo nublado;20 km;37;No se calcula; 9;Sur  9;896.5 / \r\nLa Rioja;29-Octubre-2023;20:00;Algo nublado con polvo en suspensión;15 km;30.5;No se calcula; 28;Oeste  11;947.8 / \r\nMalargue;29-Octubre-2023;20:00;Algo nublado;15 km;8.6;7.1; 61;Noroeste  9;852.5 / \r\nMendoza;29-Octubre-2023;20:00;Parcialmente nublado;15 km;28.4;No se calcula; 7;Oeste  14;922.2 / \r\nSan Martín (Mza);29-Octubre-2023;20:00;Algo nublado;15 km;28.1;No se calcula; 7;Sudoeste  24;927.2 / \r\nSan Rafael;29-Octubre-2023;20:00;Despejado con tempestad de polvo;10 km;23.5;No se calcula; 11;Oeste  46;917.4 / \r\nUspallata;29-Octubre-2023;15:00;Algo nublado con polvo levantado por viento;8 km;18.2;No se calcula; 13;Sudoeste  33;810.5 / \r\nBernardo De Irigoyen;29-Octubre-2023;20:00;Parcialmente nublado;20 km;23;No se calcula; 90;Noroeste  3;915.3 / \r\nIguazú;29-Octubre-2023;20:00;Parcialmente nublado;20 km;23.2;No se calcula; 94;Este  13;973.2 / \r\nPosadas;29-Octubre-2023;20:00;Algo nublado;20 km;28.8;33.4; 75;Sur  5;987.8 / \r\nChapelco;29-Octubre-2023;20:00;Parcialmente nublado;15 km;0.8;-4.0; 82;Oeste  18;921.3 / \r\nNeuquén;29-Octubre-2023;20:00;Parcialmente nublado;15 km;11.6;No se calcula; 30;Oeste  24;979.4 / \r\nBariloche;29-Octubre-2023;20:00;Cubierto con nevada;1.5 km;-0.2;-7.2; 90;Noroeste  35;913 / \r\nCipolletti;29-Octubre-2023;15:00;Nublado con polvo en suspensión;8 km;16.8;No se calcula; 27;Noroeste  44;970.7 / \r\nEl Bolsón;29-Octubre-2023;15:00;Cubierto con llovizna;4.0 km;6.1;No se calcula; 94;Calma;966.2 / \r\nMaquinchao;29-Octubre-2023;20:00;Algo nublado;40 km;3.2;-2.6; 59;Oeste  33;904.5 / \r\nSan Antonio Oeste;29-Octubre-2023;20:00;Parcialmente nublado;30 km;15;No se calcula; 15;Oeste  40;1002.6 / \r\nViedma;29-Octubre-2023;20:00;Cubierto;30 km;15.5;No se calcula; 30;Oeste  16;1001.4 / \r\nMetán;29-Octubre-2023;15:00;Despejado con bruma;20 km;36;No se calcula; 39;Noreste  9;905.7 / \r\nOrán;29-Octubre-2023;20:00;Parcialmente nublado con humo;4.0 km;35.8;No se calcula; 35;Calma;954.6 / \r\nRivadavia;29-Octubre-2023;18:00;Despejado;20 km;41;No se calcula; 22;Noreste  3;970.4 / \r\nSalta;29-Octubre-2023;20:00;Algo nublado;15 km;31.2;No se calcula; 28;Norte  18;867.4 / \r\nTartagal;29-Octubre-2023;18:00;Algo nublado;10 km;36;No se calcula; 31;Noreste  7;949.3 / \r\nSan Juan;29-Octubre-2023;20:00;Algo nublado;15 km;30.3;No se calcula; 7;Oeste  25;933 / \r\nSan Luis;29-Octubre-2023;20:00;Despejado con tempestad de polvo;8 km;25.5;No se calcula; 38;Este  22;920.9 / \r\nSanta Rosa del Conlara;29-Octubre-2023;20:00;Despejado;20 km;27.1;No se calcula; 15;Este  7;928.6 / \r\nVilla Reynolds;29-Octubre-2023;20:00;Despejado;10 km;22;No se calcula; 50;Este  13;946.8 / \r\nEl Calafate;29-Octubre-2023;20:00;Algo nublado;30 km;8;4.1; 36;Sudoeste  27;981 / \r\nGobernador Gregores;29-Octubre-2023;15:00;Parcialmente nublado;45 km;7;3.8; 43;Sur  18;954.2 / \r\nPerito Moreno;29-Octubre-2023;09:00;Parcialmente nublado;50 km;4.8;-1.0; 50;Oeste  40;940.4 / \r\nPuerto Deseado;29-Octubre-2023;20:00;Nublado;30 km;5.8;0.1; 73;Sur  44;991.2 / \r\nRío Gallegos;29-Octubre-2023;20:00;Parcialmente nublado con precipitación a la vista;25 km;9.3;6.3; 30;Sur  22;999.6 / \r\nSan Julián;29-Octubre-2023;20:00;Nublado;30 km;6.6;2.3; 50;Sudoeste  27;995.8 / \r\nSanta Cruz;29-Octubre-2023;15:00;Nublado con precipitación a la vista;20 km;7.2;1.0; 41;Sur  64;983 / \r\nCeres;29-Octubre-2023;20:00;Algo nublado con relámpagos sin truenos;15 km;28.8;29.2; 48;Este  9;987 / \r\nRafaela;29-Octubre-2023;18:00;Parcialmente nublado;10 km;30.2;30.6; 46;Sur  14;986.5 / \r\nReconquista;29-Octubre-2023;20:00;Nublado con tormenta;8 km;28.9;31.0; 69;Este  33;993.4 / \r\nRosario;29-Octubre-2023;20:00;Algo nublado;15 km;26.8;28.6; 71;Este  11;997.6 / \r\nSanta Fe;29-Octubre-2023;20:00;Parcialmente nublado;12 km;27.5;28.6; 58;Este  7;997.8 / \r\nSunchales;29-Octubre-2023;20:00;Parcialmente nublado;15 km;25.8;No se calcula; 70;Este  14;987.1 / \r\nVenado Tuerto;29-Octubre-2023;20:00;Despejado;10 km;22.2;No se calcula; 76;Sudeste  24;988.6 / \r\nTermas de Rio Hondo;29-Octubre-2023;20:00;Parcialmente nublado;15 km;32;33.2; 44;Oeste  11;963.9 / \r\nSantiago del Estero;29-Octubre-2023;20:00;Parcialmente nublado;10 km;33.2;34.9; 43;Calma;972.6 / \r\nRío Grande B.A.;29-Octubre-2023;20:00;Parcialmente nublado;30 km;3.6;-2.6; 60;Sur  40;1001.6 / \r\nUshuaia;29-Octubre-2023;20:00;Cubierto con nevada;2.5 km;0.6;-5.2; 92;Sudeste  25;1000.2 / \r\nTucumán;29-Octubre-2023;20:00;Parcialmente nublado;12 km;32.3;No se calcula; 34;Norte  7;946.5 / \r\nBase Belgrano II;29-Octubre-2023;18:00;Algo nublado;20 km;-6.1;-13.6; 74;Sudeste  24;939.9 / \r\nBase Esperanza;29-Octubre-2023;18:00;Algo nublado;10 km;-8.5;No se calcula; 83;Sudeste  3;1000.8 / \r\nBase Carlini;29-Octubre-2023;18:00;Parcialmente nublado;10 km;-6.6;-10.2; 88;Este  7;1003 / \r\nBase Marambio;29-Octubre-2023;20:00;Algo nublado;15 km;-12.8;-22.8; 88;Norte  27;976.8 / \r\nBase Orcadas;29-Octubre-2023;18:00;Nublado con ventisca baja;4.0 km;-7.3;-17.4; 91;Sur  42;991 / \r\nBase San Martín;29-Octubre-2023;18:00;Nublado;10 km;-4.6;-10.0; 84;Noroeste  14;1002.4 / ";
    CURL *curlDateFile;            // Archivo(?¿?) de curl donde se guardan las configuraciones para la api de la fecha
    CURL *curlSmnFile;                // Archivo(?¿?) de curl donde se guardan las configuraciones para la api del smn
    CURL *curlTelegramFile;            // Archivo(?¿?) de curl donde se guardan las configuraciones para la api de telegram
    CURLcode dateApiResponseCode;
    //CURLcode smnApiResponseCode;
    //CURLcode telegramApiResponseCode

    string_buffer_t dateApiResponse_s, smnApiResponse_s, telegramApiResponse_s;        // Implementacion de String dinamica(?¿?) para guardar la respuesta de las solicitudes http
    init_buff(&dateApiResponse_s);            // Inicializacion de la String dinamica
    init_buff(&smnApiResponse_s);            // Inicializacion de la String dinamica
    init_buff(&telegramApiResponse_s);            // Inicializacion de la String dinamica

    api_date_t date;

    curlDateFile = curl_easy_init();
    if(!curlDateFile){
        fprintf(stderr, "Fatal: curl_easy_init() error. curlDateFile\n");
        free_buff(&dateApiResponse_s);
        return 1;
    }
    curl_easy_setopt(curlDateFile, CURLOPT_URL, dateApiUrl);            // Definicion de URL para curl
    curl_easy_setopt(curlDateFile, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);            // Definicion para seguir redirecciones de la URL (1 = activadas)
    curl_easy_setopt(curlDateFile, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, write_callback);    // Definicion para que libcurl sepa cual es la funcion a llamar cuando hay datos nuevos de entrada
    curl_easy_setopt(curlDateFile, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &dateApiResponse_s);        // Definicion para que libcurl sepa la direccion de memoria de la string dinamica

    curlSmnFile = curl_easy_init();
    if(!curlSmnFile){
        fprintf(stderr, "Fatal: curl_easy_init() error. curlSmnFile\n");
        free_buff(&smnApiResponse_s);
        return 1;
    }
    //curl_easy_setopt(curlSmnFile, CURLOPT_URL, smnApiUrl);            // Definicion de URL para curl
    curl_easy_setopt(curlSmnFile, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);            // Definicion para seguir redirecciones de la URL (1 = activadas)
    curl_easy_setopt(curlSmnFile, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, write_callback);    // Definicion para que libcurl sepa cual es la funcion a llamar cuando hay datos nuevos de entrada
    curl_easy_setopt(curlSmnFile, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &smnApiResponse_s);        // Definicion para que libcurl sepa la direccion de memoria de la string dinamica

    curlTelegramFile = curl_easy_init();
    if(!curlTelegramFile){
        fprintf(stderr, "Fatal: curl_easy_init() error. curlTelegramFile\n");
        free_buff(&telegramApiResponse_s);
        return 1;
    }
    curl_easy_setopt(curlTelegramFile, CURLOPT_URL, telegramApiUrl);        // Definicion de URL para curl
    curl_easy_setopt(curlTelegramFile, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);        // Definicion para seguir redirecciones de la URL (1 = activadas)
    curl_easy_setopt(curlTelegramFile, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, write_callback);    // Definicion para que libcurl sepa cual es la funcion a llamar cuando hay datos nuevos de entrada
    curl_easy_setopt(curlTelegramFile, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &telegramApiResponse_s);        // Definicion para que libcurl sepa la direccion de memoria de la string dinamica



    dateApiResponseCode = curl_easy_perform(curlDateFile);
    if (dateApiResponseCode != CURLE_OK){
        fprintf(stderr, "Request failed: curl_easy_perform(): %s\n", curl_easy_strerror(dateApiResponseCode));
        curl_easy_cleanup(curlDateFile);
        free_buff(&dateApiResponse_s);
        return 1;
    }

    //printf("%s\n\n%lu bytes recividos\n", response.string, (unsigned long)response.size);

    char *rcvd_date = strstr(dateApiResponse_s.string, "formatted");
    sscanf(rcvd_date, "formatted\":\"%hhu/%hhu/%hu\"", &date.day, &date.month, &date.year);
    printf("Fecha: Dia: %hhu, Mes: %hhu Anio:%hu\n\r", date.day, date.month, date.year);

    tiepre_location_t *tiepre = NULL;
    char smnDataRequest[50] = {0};
    sprintf(smnDataRequest, "observaciones/tiepre%hu%hhu%hhu.txt", date.year, date.month, date.day);
    //request_smn(smnDataRequest, smnApiUrl, curlSmnFile, &smnApiResponse_s);
    write_callback(megacadena, strlen(megacadena), 1, &smnApiResponse_s);
    catalog_tiepre_request(&smnApiResponse_s, tiepre);

    curl_easy_cleanup(curlDateFile);
    curl_easy_cleanup(curlSmnFile);
    curl_easy_cleanup(curlTelegramFile);
    free_buff(&dateApiResponse_s);
    free_buff(&smnApiResponse_s);
    free_buff(&telegramApiResponse_s);
    return 0;
}

void init_buff(string_buffer_t *buff) {
    buff->size = 0;                        // primero, reseteamos la longitud del buffer
    buff->string = malloc((buff->size + 1) * sizeof(char)); // le damos al puntero string len+1 bytes para guardar datos
    buff->string[0] = '\0';                     // nos aseguramos de que haya un \0 para saber cuando termina el string
}

void free_buff(string_buffer_t *buff){
    free(buff->string);
    buff->size = 0;
    buff->string = NULL;
}

size_t write_callback(void *data, size_t size, size_t membc, void *sourceData) {
    size_t realsize = size * membc;                         // Calculamos el nuevo tamaño segun la cantidad de miembros por el tamaño?¿?¿?
    string_buffer_t *tmpbuff = (string_buffer_t *)sourceData;    // Copiamos la direccion de memoria de los datos de origen a una para evitar
                                    // hacer un cast a void cada vez que hacemos una asignacion a los datos de origen

    char *newData = realloc(tmpbuff->string, tmpbuff->size + realsize + 1);
    if (newData == NULL)
        return 1;    //no hay mas memoria

    tmpbuff->string = newData;                                 // Copiamos la direccion de memoria donde se hizo el realloc con (tmpbuff->size + realsize + 1) bytes
    memcpy(&(tmpbuff->string[tmpbuff->size]), data, realsize); // Copiamos los datos nuevos a
    tmpbuff->size += realsize;                                 // Actualizamos el tamaño de los datos guardados en la estructura de origen
    tmpbuff->string[tmpbuff->size] = 0;                        // Aseguramos que hay un \0 al final del arreglo de datos
    return size * membc;
}

void request_smn(char *smnDataRequest, char *smnApiUrl, CURL *curlSmnFile, string_buffer_t *smnApiResponse_s){
    CURLcode smnApiResponseCode;
    char *fullSmnApiUrl = malloc((strlen(smnApiUrl) + strlen(smnDataRequest)) * sizeof(char));
    memcpy(fullSmnApiUrl, smnApiUrl, strlen(smnApiUrl));
    strcat(fullSmnApiUrl, smnDataRequest);
    printf("%s\n", fullSmnApiUrl);
    curl_easy_setopt(curlSmnFile, CURLOPT_URL, fullSmnApiUrl);

    smnApiResponseCode = curl_easy_perform(curlSmnFile);
    if (smnApiResponseCode != CURLE_OK){
        fprintf(stderr, "Request failed: curl_easy_perform(): %s\n", curl_easy_strerror(smnApiResponseCode));
        free(fullSmnApiUrl);
        curl_easy_cleanup(curlSmnFile);
        free_buff(smnApiResponse_s);
        //return 1;
    }

    printf("%s\n\n%lu bytes recividos\n", smnApiResponse_s->string, (unsigned long)smnApiResponse_s->size);
    free(fullSmnApiUrl);
}

void catalog_tiepre_request(string_buffer_t *smnApiResponse_s, tiepre_location_t *tiepre){
    uint16_t locCount = get_location_cuantity_tiempre(smnApiResponse_s);

    tiepre_location_t *localTiepre = malloc(locCount * sizeof(tiepre_location_t));
    char *token = strtok(smnApiResponse_s->string, ";/");
    for (int i = 0; i < locCount; i++){
        extract_location_tiempre(token, localTiepre + i);
        token = strtok(NULL, ";/");

        extract_date_tiempre(token, localTiepre + i);
        token = strtok(NULL, ";/");

        extract_time_tiempre(token, localTiepre + i);
        token = strtok(NULL, ";/");

        extract_status_tiempre(token, localTiepre + i);
        token = strtok(NULL, ";/");

        extract_visibility_tiempre(token, localTiepre + i);
        token = strtok(NULL, ";/");

        extract_temperature_tiempre(token, localTiepre + i);
        token = strtok(NULL, ";/");

        extract_temperatureST_tiempre(token, localTiepre + i);
        token = strtok(NULL, ";/");

        extract_relative_humidity_tiempre(token, localTiepre + i);
        token = strtok(NULL, ";/");

        extract_wind_tiempre(token, localTiepre + i);
        token = strtok(NULL, ";/");

        extract_atmospheric_pressure_tiempre(token, localTiepre + i);
        token = strtok(NULL, ";/");

        printf("vuelta %d\n\r", i);
        printf("%s, %hhu/%hhu/%hu, %hhu:%hhu, %s, %hhu Km, %5.2f Cº, %5.2f Cº, %hhu%% H/R, %hhu Km/h %s, %f KPa, vuelta %d\n", localTiepre[i].location, localTiepre[i].day, localTiepre[i].month, localTiepre[i].year, localTiepre[i].hour, localTiepre[i].minute, localTiepre[i].status, localTiepre[i].visibility, localTiepre[i].temperature, localTiepre[i].temperatureST, localTiepre[i].relativeHumidity, localTiepre[i].windSpeed, localTiepre[i].windDirection, localTiepre[i].atmosphericPressure, i);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < locCount; i++){
        printf("%s, %hhu/%hhu/%hu, %hhu:%hhu, %s, %hhu Km, %5.2f Cº, %5.2f Cº, %hhu%% H/R, %hhu Km/h %s, %f KPa\n", localTiepre[i].location, localTiepre[i].day, localTiepre[i].month, localTiepre[i].year, localTiepre[i].hour, localTiepre[i].minute, localTiepre[i].status, localTiepre[i].visibility, localTiepre[i].temperature, localTiepre[i].temperatureST, localTiepre[i].relativeHumidity, localTiepre[i].windSpeed, localTiepre[i].windDirection, localTiepre[i].atmosphericPressure);
    }
}

uint16_t get_location_cuantity_tiempre(string_buffer_t *smnApiResponse_s){
    uint16_t locCount = 0, byteCount = 0;
    while (smnApiResponse_s->string[byteCount] != '\0' && byteCount  < smnApiResponse_s->size){
        if(smnApiResponse_s->string[byteCount] == '/')
            locCount++;
        byteCount++;
    }
    printf("%d localidades encontradas!\n\r", locCount);
    return locCount;
}

void extract_location_tiempre(char *token, tiepre_location_t *remoteTiepre){
    if(token[0] == ' ')
        token += 3;
    remoteTiepre->locStrSize = strlen(token);
    printf("pre. len: %ld, token: %s\n", strlen(token) * sizeof(char), token);
    remoteTiepre->location = malloc(strlen(token) * sizeof(char));
    strcpy(remoteTiepre->location, token);
    printf("primer token: %s\n\r", remoteTiepre->location);
}

void extract_date_tiempre(char *token, tiepre_location_t *remoteTiepre){
    char month[11] = {0};
    sscanf(token, "%hhu-%[^-]-%hu", &remoteTiepre->day, month, &remoteTiepre->year);
    //printf("%hhu-%s-%hu", localTiepre[i]->day, month, localTiepre[i]->year);
    for (int j = 0; j < 12; j++){
        if (!strcmp(month, meses[j])){
            remoteTiepre->month = j + 1;
            break;
        }
    }
    printf("segundo token: %hhu/%hhu/%hu\n\r", remoteTiepre->day, remoteTiepre->month, remoteTiepre->year);
}

void extract_time_tiempre(char *token, tiepre_location_t *remoteTiepre){
    sscanf(token, "%hhu:%hhu", &remoteTiepre->hour, &remoteTiepre->minute);
    printf("tercer token: %hhu:%hhu\n\r", remoteTiepre->hour, remoteTiepre->minute);
}

void extract_status_tiempre(char *token, tiepre_location_t *remoteTiepre){
    remoteTiepre->locStrSize = strlen(token);
    printf("pre. len: %ld, token: %s\n", strlen(token) * sizeof(char), token);
    remoteTiepre->status = malloc(strlen(token) * sizeof(char));
    printf("post\n");
    strcpy(remoteTiepre->status, token);
    printf("cuarto token: %s\n\r", remoteTiepre->status);
}

void extract_visibility_tiempre(char *token, tiepre_location_t *remoteTiepre){
    remoteTiepre->visibility = (uint8_t) atoi(token);
    printf("quinto token\n\r");
}

void extract_temperature_tiempre(char *token, tiepre_location_t *remoteTiepre){
    remoteTiepre->temperature = atof(token);
    printf("sexto token\n\r");
}

void extract_temperatureST_tiempre(char *token, tiepre_location_t *remoteTiepre){
    remoteTiepre->temperatureST = atof(token);
    printf("septimo token\n\r");
}

void extract_relative_humidity_tiempre(char *token, tiepre_location_t *remoteTiepre){
    remoteTiepre->relativeHumidity = (uint8_t) atoi(token);
    printf("octavo token\n\r");
}

void extract_wind_tiempre(char *token, tiepre_location_t *remoteTiepre){
    char direction[10] = {0};
    sscanf(token, "%s %hhu", direction, &remoteTiepre->windSpeed);
    remoteTiepre->windDirection[0] = direction[0];
    if(strlen(direction) > 6){
        remoteTiepre->windDirection[1] = direction[3];
        remoteTiepre->windDirection[2] = 0;
    } else {
        remoteTiepre->windDirection[1] = 0;
    }
    printf("noveno token\n\r");
}

void extract_atmospheric_pressure_tiempre(char *token, tiepre_location_t *remoteTiepre){
    remoteTiepre->atmosphericPressure = atof(token);
    printf("decimo token\n\r");
}
```

El problema ocurre cuando quiero extraer el nombre de la ubicación o el estado de la misma. En ambos casos los datos son cadenas de texto. El programa muere repentinamente cuando ejecuta la instrucción: `remoteTiepre->location = malloc(strlen(token) * sizeof(char));`, sea en la función `extract_location_tiempre` o `extract_status_tiempre`. Lo desconcertante acá, es que el bucle donde extraigo y guardo todos los datos se ejecuta varias veces hasta que llega a morir. Probando con una cadena constante (para que las actualizaciones del clima no alteren mis resultados) siempre se rompe en la misma iteracion. Eso es, hasta que los datos se actualizan y ahí puede ser que cambie algo y por lo tanto cambia el numero de bucle en el que se rompe el código.

Honestamente se me están acabando las ideas, y lo mas gracioso de todo es que quise usar valgrind para ver si podía extraer información de utilidad, y cuando lo ejecuto en valgrind, ademas de los incontables memory leaks que se que los tengo que corregir, el código se ejecuta exitosamente, y extrae todos los datos de todas las localidades.

Nota al pie de pagina: Para recibir datos de la api, comenten la linea `write_callback(megacadena, strlen(megacadena), 1, &smnApiResponse_s);` y descomenten la linea `request_smn(smnDataRequest, smnApiUrl, curlSmnFile, &smnApiResponse_s);`.